# R arules / apriori - how to actually implement

Tags: sql, r, apriori, arules, pmml

I've been working with the `arules` package and the `apriori` algorithm to create some rules for a group of transactions.  Now that I have some rules, I'm curious how to implement them - either in R or SQL Server 2008 R2.

Does anyone have any experience doing this?  It appears that the package can write a PMML file but I can't find an example of how to convert this to SQL.  Also the package has a predict function but it appears to be for scoring clustering.

Answer (score 2):

You need to be more specific because it depends on what you want to do.

Association rules are typically used as a descriptive tool to look at data. People often use visualization here (see package `arulesViz`). Sometimes people used association rules to create associative classifiers.
For classification, you can look at the package `arulesCBA`. Recommender systems can also be built using association rules. For creating such recommendations look at package `recommenderlab`. If you have a tool that can ingest PMML for deploying models, then you can use that. These tools might create SQL code from rules for whatever the indented application is.

Hope this helps!